# Sharing entity between multiple bounded contexts in hibernate in domain driven development

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity, domain-driven-design

I'm currently learning domain driven development(DDD). After watching some tutorials I want to model my old school project from clasic SOA to DDD. I identified 3 bounded contexts(for now): secretary-management(CRUD for students and professors), professor-task (create tasks for students) and student-task(upload task solution). The names are not properly chosen and this is only an overview of the application.

The point is there will be 2 different Professor entities: one in management which will contains name, addres, email and other stuff and one in professor-task which will contain id and name.

My question is how will I model this using hibernate and JPA? I was thinking about creating a package with all the entities in the application, annotated with JPA annotations, each with all the field necessary, and in every bounded context to have other classes which contains only the fields necessary in that bounded context. The repository would have to map from that particular class to the JPA entity. Are there any better solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you intend to deploy all 3 bounded contexts within the same application or will each be considered their own deployable, perhaps microservice?

Comment: I will deploy them in the same application, either in different packages or in different modules

Comment: Why not mapping individual classes in each BC? A BC is also a technological boundary, where the appropriate tools shall be chosen for it.

Comment: I can't do that because even if the professor from one BC is different to the professor from another BC, in the end they refer to only one professor. If I were to have 2 classes mapped to 2 different tables, I would have update one table every time the other one would be updated. If that is what you mean in your comment.

Comment: Most DDD practitioners strongly suggests not distributing (sharing) entities. In essence, this means that means an entity should be confined to a single class in a single domain inside a single bounded contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not share your persistence between bounded contexts. You create coupling on something that should be decoupled by design.

If you have "it is the same thing" feeling - reconsider your context boundaries. May be you need to merge them. If something resists the split, you might be breaking the cohesion but your bounded context must have high cohesion.

Typically different bounded context have different concerns even on something that is the same in real life. In such case, the domain objects with the same name would look completely different. This is, essentially, why they are called "bounded *contexts*" since words have different meanings being put in different context.